# Integrating Facebook Audience Network in exoplayer in Android

Tags: android, exoplayer, facebook-audience-network

I have an Android media app in which I am using Exoplayer to play the video. I want to integrate Facebook Audience Network with Exoplayer to get pre-roll, mid-roll and post-roll ads in my app. I saw Facebook developer docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs  but did not get anything related to Exoplayer integation.
Can any one suggest any sample app or doc link. It will be great help for me.

Thank you in advance.